# Linux Bash Trying to write checklist progress "bar" of sorts. Replace the same line

Tags: linux, bash, progress-bar

Sorry if I am not giving you enough info, this is my first time posting here.

I am trying to make this in a bash script.

> Downloading...............

"run bash commands and when they are done, replace the "Downloading..." text with the text bellow **in the same line aka space**."

> Downloading............... DONE!

**go to next line and show**

> Installing................

"run bash commands again and when they are done, replace the "Installing..." text with the text bellow **in the same line aka space**."

> Installing................ DONE!

I hope you get what I mean. Thanks in advance.

I've tried:

```
#/bin/bash
tput sc # save cursor
printf "Something that I made up for this string"
sleep 1
tput rc;tput el # rc = restore cursor, el = erase to end of line
printf "Another message for testing"
sleep 1
tput rc;tput el
printf "Yet another one"
sleep 1
tput rc;tput el
```

But it doesn't make new lines, it just uses one line to show all text.

Comment: You have described what you want to do but you have not described what you have tried and what specific problem you have.

Comment: True, because I have tried so many things and nothing worked. So do I write every example I did? waste of space. The problem is I can't wrap my head around it. I'm a novice "coder" as in I started a few days ago.

Comment: You can show the attempt that you think is best and describe a specific problem you had with that attempt. At a minimum that will tell us what your thinking is and someone may be able to point out a specific problem in your approach.

Comment: One approach: Run each command in the background. Then in the foreground poll for the background process - print a dot if background process is still running, otherwise print the done msg and terminate the polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you pulled the `tput` code from somewhere, and I'm guessing that 'somewhere' also explained that `tput` is being used to overwrite the same line multiple times (as your script actually does).

From your description it doesn't sound like you need to overwrite any lines so using `tput` is the wrong solution.

If I understand your description correctly you should be able to do everything you want with some (relatively) simple `printf` commands, eg:

```
printf "Downloading .... "                 # no '\n' in the output so cursor remains at end of current line
# run your bash commands here 
printf "DONE!\n"                           # append to end of current line and then add a new line (\n)

printf "Installing .... "                  # no '\n' in the output so cursor remains at end of current line
# run more bash commands here
printf "DONE!\n"                           # append to end of the current line and then add a new line (\n)
```

Keep in mind that if any of your 'bash commands' generate **any** output then the cursor will be moved (probably to a new line) thus messing up your output.  Net result is that you'll need to make sure your 'bash commands' do not generate any output to stdout/stderr (alternatively, make sure all output - stdout/stderr - is redirected to files).

If your requirement is to have the 'bash commands' send output to the terminal then you may need to go back to using `tput` ... but that's going to depend on exactly how you want the output to appear.

**NOTE**: If this (above) does not meet your requirement then please update the question with more details.

Comment: This example worked perfectly. Seems stupid simple. I'm a novice in bash, this must have seen trivial to you. I am pushing outputs to > /dev/null 2>&1    Hopefully that is ok Thank you very much

Comment: @no112358 good to hear this addressed your requirement; consider Walter's comment; thanks